# Two classes implementing interface with different type arguments

Tags: java

```
class SingleTon{
   Data<A> a;
   Data<B> b;
   Data<C> c;
   // ... etc
   class Data<O extends I<O>>{
       O o;
       public void update(O o){
          this.o.update(o);
       }   
   }
}
interface I<T>{
   void update(T t);
}

class A implements I<A>{

    private String a;

    @Override
    public void update(A a) {
        this.a = a.a;
    }
}

class B extends A implements I<B>{

    private String b;

    @Override
    public void update(B b) {
       super.update(b);
       this.b = b.b;
    }
}
class C implements I<C> {public void update(C c){}}
```

This code cannot be compiled, because super and sub-classes trying to implements the same interface but with different type arguments.

Interface I cannot be inherited with different type arguments (A,B), anyone has a workaround to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are saying that code doesn't work, then please provide more detailed definition of 'doesnt work', i.e. error message, etc...

Comment: it cannot be compiled, it's not about multiple inheritance, it's about sub and super classes trying to implement the same interface but with different type arguments

Comment: @AndroidDev - please add this detail to the question, rather than leaving it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

No workaround are possible with such a hierarchy : in `B` you want to implement the `i` interface with two distinct generic types : `A` and `B`.
Generics are designed to bring more type safety and this possible ambiguity defeats that. From the client of the class, why `update(B b)` would be valid but `update(A a)` would be not ?
So the compiler will never accept it.

But with composition you could do :

```
class B  implements i<B>{
    private A a;
    private String b;

    @Override
    public void update(B b) {
       super.update(b);
       this.b = b.b;
    }
}
```

And now you can use the `A a` field if needed from the `B` instance.

Comment: thank you for the answer, this looks good except that I am using an API and sometimes I need the inheritance

Comment: You are welcome. In your case unfortunately the inheritancy is not wished. With the wrapper/composition and delegation you should all the same get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With the inheritance model given below, you'll achieve a contact of `i` through `B` in `A`. You don't really need to implement `i` for `class B<T>`.

See the example below:

```
interface i<T> {


}

class A<T> implements i<T> {

}

class B<T> extends A<T> {

}
```

Hope it helps you to understand the structure!

Comment: thank you for the answer, the problem with this structure is that I cannot do this:
b.update(newB);
a.update(newA);

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what is needed, but this code is compiled))

```
interface i<T extends i<T>> {
    void update(T t);
}

class A<Q extends A<Q>> implements i<Q> {
    private String a;

    @Override
    public void update(A a) {
        this.a = a.a;
    }
}

class B<X extends B<X>> extends A<X> implements i<X>  {
    String b;

    @Override
    public void update(X b) {
        super.update(b);
        this.b = b.b;
    }
}
```